# The bat roost microclimate measurement

Tags: prepositional-phrases, style, modifiers

The bat roost microclimate measurement.

The measurement of the bat roost microclimate.

Which one is easily readable?

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Peter Hi Peter, just trying to ask if the sentence format is understandable by everyone.

Comment: Neither is clear. What sort of measurement is "the" measurement?!? Humidity, CO2, temperature, or all three for example? All three would be measurements - plural.

Comment: @MaxW Microclimate includes: humidity, light intensity, temperature, et al.

Comment: High Wowe, welcome to ELL! This question is pretty short and vague. It could use some more detail to help us give you a better answer. You should read through [this answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/465/15406) to get an idea of what a good question on this site looks like.

Answer (score 1):

It is common in scientific writing to chain nouns together and make them act as modifiers. This happens in non-scientific writing too, but not to such a degree.

> bat roost microclimate measurement

What roost?  the { bat {roost} }

What microclimate? the { { bat {roost} } microclimate }

What measurement? the { { { bat {roost} } microclimate } measurement}

But if you were writing an article for a lay audience, which would appear not in a scientific journal but in a periodical with a wider audience, this constipated style would not be used, and prepositional phrases using **of** and **in** would be used instead:

**... measurement of the microclimate in the bat roost...**

This choice is *stylistic*. Both versions are *grammatical*.